# "Too many of your edits were rejected" While Accessing the Review Queue

Tags: support, editing, review-queue

I got 500 Reputations today and can see 'Review' in the Top. That means I got the Privilege "Access Review Queues".
Privilege Type: Moderation Privilege
Awarded At: 500 Reputation

But in Review Queue 'First Posts' & 'Late Answers' I can see its mentioned as "Too many of your edits were rejected". I believe some of my edits related to Posts or Answers got rejected recently.

Could you please let me know when this will be removed and will be able to see the Review Queue?

Comment: It was your wiki edits. Many of them were rejected with the reason *This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.* I think you were being too vague.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thnx for your reply & understood... One more query on this, When this will be Reopened for me? Means the "Access to Review Queues'  -  'First Posts' & 'Late Answers'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are [evaluated on a rolling 7 day basis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days).

> When deciding on whether we should ban or not, we now look at your last 7 days of activity.
>
> If `(rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5`, you will be auto-banned.